# What does mean brackets in: require("./config")[somevar]

Tags: node.js

I'm learning Node.js and in a source code I found this:

```
config:  require("./config")[env]
```

but can't understand the syntax of these brackets. I know that `require('something')(somevar)`  passes the variable `somevar` to requiring module. But what means brackets in example above, do they pass var or something else?

Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a basic syntactic feature of the language which should be looked up in the language spec or an introductory tutorial.

Comment: Sir, I looked in documentation but didn't find, if you would write it I would be very appreciated

Comment: require("./config") returns an object. env is some string-var. you can lookup properties of an object with the bracket notation obj[someVar]. this is what's happening here. require('./config') returns the config object, which probably has properties like ('dev', 'prod').

Answer (score 0):

`config.js` returns an object.

```
module.exports = {
  "env" : "Hello World"
};
```

[Bracket notation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) is defined clearly in the specification.

Comment: thank you for response, sorry but I don't undesrtand does require("./config")[env] pass env variable like require("./config")(env) would?

Comment: here is the link where I found it. https://github.com/bigohstudios/node_app/blob/master/config/application.js on line 10

Comment: Sir, I looked in documentation but didn't find, if you would write it I would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have at the top

```
var env         = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
```

Then you have later on

```
, config:  require("./config")[env]
```

This is essentially the same as..

```
, config:  require("./config")[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'devel']
```

So what they're saying is get the config set by NODE_ENV, or assume we're running in a 'devel' environment and get that config.